# How chainlink can be used for verifying Biometric data

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, chainlink

Chainlink oracles are solving the real world problems in a big way. I am working on a project, which solves the user biometric identity privacy. So my question is that we trust chainlink oracles because it fetches data from multiple sources and verify them in blockchain. What if the data is available at single source like the repository of users biometric data.

- How biometric data can be verified with chainlink?
- How chainlink can make sure the the database is reliable?
- How chainlink cross reference the database?
- What exactly is the cross reference the database?

Answer (score 1):

These are great questions. It seems their root comes from having data available from a single source. That would be a limiting factor compared to something with multiple data sources.

If the data can be cryptographically signed at the source, it should be 'verifiable' from a tamper resistance standpoint.

I'm not sure I understand the last two points there, though. Perhaps looking at AnyAPI might help answer these?

https://blog.chain.link/apis-smart-contracts-and-how-to-connect-them/
https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data/